# Need help understanding C program to find that machines IP address

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, redhat

I am not getting this assignment about finding the IP address of the machine. I need help understanding the logic of this code.  Our college lab uses proxy server; will this code work on a computer without proxy?

```
      #include <stdio.h>          /* stderr, stdout */
      #include <netdb.h>          /* hostent struct, gethostbyname() */
      #include <arpa/inet.h>      /* inet_ntoa() to format IP address */
      #include <netinet/in.h>     /* in_addr structure */

      int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        struct hostent *host;     /* host information */
        struct in_addr h_addr;    /* internet address */
        if (argc != 2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: nslookup <inet_address>\n");
          exit(1);
        }
        if ((host = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "(mini) nslookup failed on '%s'\n", argv[1]);
          exit(1);
        }
        h_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *) host->h_addr_list[0]);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", inet_ntoa(h_addr));
        exit(0);
      }
```

Comment: Did you read the manpages of the functions that are being used? What part don't you understand after that?

Answer (score 2):

The 2 key methods of interest here are:

1. [gethostbyname()](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Names.html) - The gethostbyname function retrieves host information
2. [inet_ntoa](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) - convert ip add to in_addr

Try to be specific, where are you having problem understanding the code.

The code works with me.

```
$./a.out nslookup
```

returns host ip.

Comment: Not getting the pointer variable *host and condition to be tested in if()

Answer (score 1):

`netdb.h` - definitions for network database operations
`arpa/inet.h` - definitions for internet operations
`netinet/in.h` - Internet address family
The `gethostname()` function returns the standard host name for the current machine. 
`inet_ntoa(h_addr)`   To convert an IP address from 32-bit network format back to dotted decimal.

These are the basic understanding terms. Most importantly use `google` for detail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the gethostbyname function performs a DNS request which returns the hostent structure filed.
It could be interesting for you to snif the network with wireshark for instance to look what the traffic looks like.